# How to merge data from multiple rows into single column in new table?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How do I merge data from multiple rows in one table to a single column in a new table?

```
create table new_paragraphs
(
    id NUMBER
    paragraph CLOB
);

create table old_paragraphs
(
   id
   paragraph CLOB
);

merge into new_paragraphs  a
using (select * from old_paragraphs) b
on (id = id)
when matched then
update set a.paragraph = a.paragraph || b.paragraph;
-- Results in error: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

The above throws an exception.

Comment: Actually, it results in `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work if `id` were a primary key in at least *old_paragraphs* (or if it were unique for each id found in *new_paragraph*)

Other than that, you want to use aliases in `on (id = id)` so that it reads `on (a.id = b.id)`:

```
merge into new_paragraphs  a
using (select * from old_paragraphs) b
on (a.id = b.id)
when matched then
update set a.paragraph = a.paragraph || b.paragraph;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a `MERGE` here?  Why not a simple `UPDATE` (assuming `ID` is the primary key of both tables)

```
UPDATE new_paragraphs a
   SET paragraph = (select a.paragraph || b.paragraph
                      from old_paragraphs b
                     where a.id = b.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM old_paragraphs b
                WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: There is more than 1 row per id in old_paragraphs. When I run your query, I get the exception ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: @firebird - OK.  So `ID` is not the primary key of `OLD_PARAGRAPHS`?  Do you care what order the data from the old paragraphs is appended?